# FastUrlFilter is not applying for multiple domains

Tags: web-crawler, stormcrawler

Working on Storm Crawler 1.11 and Elastic Search 6.5.x and tried to apply the **fastfilterfilter**. First Filter is working fine and remaining filters are crawling only parent url. Is there anything missing in my configuration or any changes do I need to make to crawl all five urls.

**My seed Url**

```
https://www.abce.com/ghi/   seed=ghi
https://www.abce.com/jkl/   seed=jkl
https://www.abce.com/mno/   seed=mno
https://mnop.edu/   seed=mnop
https://jqkl.edu/   seed=jqkl
```

**fasturlfilter.json**

```
[  
   {  
      "scope":"domain:abce.com",
      "patterns":[  
         "AllowPath /ghi/",
         "AllowPath /jkl/",
         "AllowPath /mno/",
         "DenyPath .+"
      ]
   },
   {  
      "scope":"domain:mnop.edu",
      "patterns":[  
      "AllowPath /",
         "DenyPath .+"
      ]
   },
      {  
      "scope":"domain:jqkl.edu",
      "patterns":[ 
      "AllowPath /",
         "DenyPath .+"
      ]
   }

]
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a unit test with the URLs and rules above and can't find any problem. Please check that there aren't any other filters preventing outlinks to be added.